# Convert ASCII to HEX keeping line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, hex, ascii

OK so I'm making a ASCII to HEX converter and it works fine, but when i insert line breaks it replaces them with this character -> Ú

ie
turns this

> 1
>   2
>   3

to this

> 1Ú2Ú3

Code under command buttons

```
    private void asciiToHex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HexConverter HexConvert =new HexConverter();
        string sData=textBox1.Text;
        textBox2.Text = HexConvert.StringToHexadecimal(sData);
    }

    private void hexToAscii_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HexConverter HexConvert = new HexConverter();
        string sData = textBox1.Text;
        textBox2.Text = HexConvert.HexadecimalToString(sData);
    }
```

Code under HexConverter.cs

```
public class HexConverter
{
    public string HexadecimalToString(string Data)
    {
        string Data1 = "";
        string sData = "";

        while (Data.Length > 0)
        //first take two hex value using substring.
        //then  convert Hex value into ascii.
        //then convert ascii value into character.
        {
            Data1 = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(Data.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
            sData = sData + Data1;
            Data = Data.Substring(2, Data.Length - 2);
        }
        return sData;
    }
    public string StringToHexadecimal(string Data)
    {
        //first take each charcter using substring.
        //then  convert character into ascii.
        //then convert ascii value into Hex Format

        string sValue;
        string sHex = "";
        foreach (char c in Data.ToCharArray())
        {
            sValue = String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToUInt32(c));
            sHex = sHex + sValue;
        }
        return sHex;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you need to keep the newlines? If so it would be easiest to process the input line by line and join them afterwards. Otherwise the other answers will point you in the right direction.

Comment: It really depends on how you get your data - if it's from a file then reading directly lines (with File.ReadAllLines for example) would be easiest. For a generic solution simply split the string using `str.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` - that will give you an array; make a new array or list, put in it the transformed strings, and then use `string.Join("\r\n", newArray)` to build it back up together with the newlines. Actually it would be better to replace `"\r\n"` with `Environment.NewLine`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `String.Format("{0:X}", Convert.ToUInt32(c))` does not zero-pad its output to two digits, so `\r\n` becomes `DA` instead of `0D0A`. You'll get a similar problem, but worse, with `\t` (which becomes `9` instead of `09`, which will cause misalignment for subsequent characters as well).

To zero-pad to two digits, you can use `X2` instead of bare `X`; or, more generally, you can use `Xn` to zero-pad to *n* digits. (See [the "Standard Numeric Format Strings" page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).)

Comment: For reference, the format specifier is 'X2' - but you can replace the 2 with other numbers as well to get that many zero paddings.

Comment: @AlexPaven: Thanks! I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: great explanation of the theory, where is the answer to the problem? especially after you called a legitimate answer a hack.  no code requirements were posted, only a question on how to solve a problem.

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II: LOL. Well, I've added "the answer to the problem" now. :-)

Comment: @ruakh your solution still takes more process than the second option in my answer, making it a less optimal solution (and more of a hack).  So, tell you what, I'll trade you the removal of -1's if you're that upset.

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II: Clearly, it's you who's upset; and I don't think there's much I can do about that, sorry. You can't bribe me into retracting my downvote. But I hope, for your sake, that you become a better programmer someday.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`System.Convert.ToUInt32(hexString)`, use

`uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);`

MSDN says the ["AllowHexSpecifier flag indicates that the string to be parsed is always interpreted as a hexadecimal value"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

the laziest thing you could do is do a `string.replace("Ú","\r\n")` on the result.  Unless there were a compelling reason not to do it this way, I would start here.

Otherwise, in your Char loop, look for the NewLine char and add it as-is to your string.

Comment: -1, sorry. Hacking around bugs without understanding their root cause is a recipe for disaster. In the OP's case, (s)he hasn't noticed it yet, but `"abcd\tefgh\tijkl"` will have a much more complex and bizarre-seeming result, one that cannot be hacked around in the way that you describe.

Comment: not caring about the OPs unaksed questions and problems does not make this a hack.  Does this solve the problem? Yes, therefore not a hack and not an invalid answer.

Comment: It *doesn't* solve the problem, though. It doesn't even *identify* the problem, it merely seeks to conceal the problem and hack around it. (And I can't imagine what you think the word "hack" means, that you think this isn't one. Sometimes hacks are appropriate or even necessary, but they're still hacks.)

Comment: Are we talking about answering the question or producing Production quality code? if the former, then both of my answers are correct; if the later, then only my second answer is valid.  As it takes less processing power to do a comparison (IF block) than to convert an unnecessary char twice, this is one of the least bad solutions on the page.

Comment: Neither of your "answers" answers the question, and neither of them produces production-quality code. If you think otherwise, then I can only count myself lucky that I've never had to work on code you'd written.